# Connecting to Cassandra through python without validating SSL

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to connect to Cassandra without validating SSL as below, but still getting permission error

```
cluster = Cluster(['10.1.1.1'], ssl_options=dict(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1),
auth_provider=DSEPlainTextAuthProvider(username='user',password='p@ssword'))

session = cluster.connect()
```

Comment: Can you put the error that you got ?

Comment: Unable to connect to any servers, {'10.1.1.1:9042': PermissionError(1, "Tried connecting to ['10.1.1.1',9042]. Last error:[SSL:NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE]

Comment: Remove `ssl_options` and give it a try.  If you're not using SSL, you shouldn't need to specify that.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error message you have written as a comment